# Destroy and Spawn(Respawn) Objects in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have a game project. You have a ball that you can control with arrow keys. Purpose is, you will collecting an object. Object will destroy when i going over it, and respawn in random location of ground. Btw, you need to do that in 30 seconds. I couldnt destroy and respawn part. May you help me? (C#)

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: No, i just dont know how to do that part. I dont want writing code for me, just need a doing way. Like "You need to use first blabla, and blabla for respawn" .

Comment: There are alot of tutorials out there. To spawn an object check [instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html). To destroy a gameObject, check [gameObject Destroy](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html)

Comment: If you want to respawn an object immediatly you might want to consider not destroying it, but rather just changing its position.

Comment: But respawn will be in random position. Maybe object respawn in same position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use collisions to destroy object. Run over it and `yield`. After that you can create couple of spawn points (for more randomness you can move the spawn points).